# HttpResponseMessage content is not getting serialized for BadRequest responses

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have ASP.NET application, with some MVC and WebAPI controllers in there. MVC 5.1 and WebAPI 2.1. There is no tricky configuration at all, the only thing is getting configured is removed XML formatter:

```
public static class WebApi
{
    public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var formatters = config.Formatters;
        formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
}
```

There is simple DTO to put data returned from controller action together:

```
public class TokenResponse
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string error { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code:

```
[NoHttpResponseCaching]
public class TokenController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, TokenRequest tokenRequest)
    {
        try
        {
            // do some stuff
            var response = new TokenResponse { ... };
            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
        }
        catch (TokenRequestValidationException ex)
        {
            _logger.WriteError(ex);
            var response = new TokenResponse { error = ex.ErrorToDisplay };
            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if everything fine, I have my TokenResponse serialized to JSON, as expected, but if there is exception occurring, execution flow is coming into catch block and response body is equal to "Bad Request", this is the RAW dump of response from Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 18 Jun 2014 08:25:53 GMT
Content-Length: 11

Bad Request
```

Tried to return anonymous object having some random named properties instead of using TokenResponse, getting same response:

```
return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new {klhjaoiubf = "kjhaflkjh"});
```

And I'm stuck at this point trying to understand why I'm not getting my object serialized in response body and how to change it. Anyone, any ideas, why my object is getting ignored when response code is BadRequest?

Comment: How is the section for custom errors configured in your web.config? And have a look at this blog which explains how to get the error details: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/04/18/custom-errors-and-error-detail-policy-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: I ran this. I get that 'kl..' anonymous object in the response, I used Postman google chrome addon to debug.

Comment: Schadensbegrenzer, you mean this one?

    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="Error.html" responseMode="File" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="Error.html" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>

Comment: Ah, yea - <customErrors mode="Off" />

Comment: Schadensbegrenzer, red that post, this guy explaining that "While the customErrors element affects requests for ASPX and MVC, it does nothing for Web API.", so web.config custom errors section should not affect it anyhow. I tried to configure WebAPI like he is writing:

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

and it's still the same, "Bad Request" instead of serialized object.

Comment: Typist, yea, I know that it should work, but it seems that I have something in my configuration that I'm totally missing. And I'm trying to figure out what exactly...